# Proper Scopehandling in GUICE @Singleton vs. Default Scope

Tags: java, scope, singleton, guice

There has been a similar question asked already at (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-guice/Should$20Guice-Injected$20DAO$27s$20be$20Singletons$3F/google-guice/3B8XrwB-p18/B6OF13HWRnEJ) but I don't think it has received a satisfying answer yet.

The baseline:
We are using Guice in a JSF/Primefaces webapplication running on Tomcat. Persistence is handled via JPA/Hibernate.

Right now ALL our DAOs (approx. one per Entity) are annotated as @Singleton. The only reason for this seem to be performance concerns as another (non JSF but Webservice) part of the application will receive thousands of hits per seconds and our main developer believes, that constructing a DAO Singleton once and then getting it in a synchronized way is cheaper than to always inject a new instance (which is the Guice Default Scope).
This goes contrary to what the Google Guice Wiki writes about Scopes: If the object is stateless and inexpensive to create, scoping is unnecessary. Leave the binding unscoped and Guice will create new instances as they're required...Although singletons save object creation (and later garbage collection), initialization of the singleton requires synchronization; ...

Now, what exactly does "initialization of the singleton" mean in this context? Is initialization done once? Everytime it is injected?

Is the assumption correct that, with the above scenario (thousands of hits per second) using @Singleton annotated DAOs is faster and better resource wise than using Default Scope?

As we use @Singleton for our DAOs we don't inject the EntityManager directly but use an EntityManagerProvider which, as I understand it, is the correct way as the Provider is considered threadsafe which is a requirement for @Singleton.
Is there a "Google approved" way to include Hibernate using DAOs in your web application?

Comment: I believe the `Leave the binding unscoped and Guice will create new instances as they're required...` comment is there to prevent developers from mixing scopes. Can you add more info about your `EntitiyManager` scope? How do you handle open and close of EM context? Personally, I think `Singleton` is in place and will perform better, cuz is little on GC and initialization. Anyway you have to know how to mix injection with different scopes and inject `EntityManager` as a provider, what you did, so you are all set, gj.

Comment: > Can you add more info about your EntitiyManager scope?
What do you mean by EntityManager scope?

How do you handle open and close of EM context? 
---
Right now we are using guice-persist's @Transactional annotation but as I learned that it is not maintained anymore we are probably going to switch to onami-persist.

Comment: Where did you learn that `guice-persist` is not maintained anymore?  It seems to have recent commits.

Comment: The last non Beta Release is from March 24, 2011.  
Also scl's answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-guice/y2N1PSNmhGk

Comment: @MichaelFrank The last non-beta release of Guice period was on March 24, 2011.

Comment: Ahm, yes, that's what I wrote? So?

Comment: I just mean that's not a reason to consider guice-persist unmaintained, since its last release was the same as Guice itself.  Unless you consider Guice unmaintained too.

Comment: Overall I agree though, expecially in light of [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-guice/persist%7Csort:date/google-guice/Dp9nWdmDbUs/AWkQYqG8EgoJ) thread, that guice-persist is at most minimally-maintained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Although singletons save object creation (and later garbage
>   collection), initialization of the singleton requires synchronization;
>   ...
>
> Now, what exactly does "initialization of the singleton" mean in this
>   context? Is initialization done once? Everytime it is injected?

[Here](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/core/src/com/google/inject/internal/SingletonScope.java#L35) is the implementation of the singleton scope (it is slightly different in the released version of Guice, but the following points still stand).  Every time a singleton-scoped dependency is injected anywhere, the `get()` method on that provider will be called to get the instance.

Double-checked locking is used so that after the singleton has been created for the first time, future calls to `get()` are cheap: they read a single `volatile` field and return.

On the other hand, using `@Singleton` DAOs means you have to access the `EntityManager` through a `Provider` in every method, which involves looking up the `EntityManager` in a `HashMap` in a `ThreadLocal` somewhere.

Conclusion: the only way to find what choice is better for performance is to benchmark both and pick the faster one.  You'll probably find that both choices are fast enough, in which case you should pick the cleanest one.

Comment: I did some (non exhaustive) performance tests and couldn't measure any significant difference between Singleton and the default Scope, even after doing tests with 100k+ requests to trigger garbage collection runs etc. So, I'll accept your answer as it didn't really answer my questions but it was the most informative anyway (especially the info about double-checked locking). Still, I find it weird that there is no proper information from Google Dev about this, there are no answers from Google developers on the google guice mailing list and some tutorials insist on using the Singleton Scope.